# How can I add a 401 response to all paths in Swagger

Tags: response, swagger

I have a rest api that I want to document in Swagger.
On all requests the API can respond with a 401.

So instead of defining the 401 again again and again for each path (not so DRY). 
I want to define that all paths can return a 401.

Is this possible?

Comment: Btw, there's a feature request to have default responses to avoid duplication: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/563.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, this is not possible. You will need to annotate each API endpoint with @ApiResponse. The only annotations available at the class level are @Api and @ApiModel . For details, please refer to this link -

http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModel.html

Answer (score 15):

I don't think this is a perfect solution but I've done this in an attempt to DRY it up a bit.

In the [root swagger schema](http://swagger.io/specification/#dataTypeFormat) you can define a `responses` object which, as defined by the Swagger Spec:

> An object to hold responses that can be used across operations. This
>   property does not define global responses for all operations.

```yaml
responses:
  400:
    description: Bad Request
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
  401:
    description: Unauthorized
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
  403:
    description: Forbidden
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
  500:
    description: Internal Server Error
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/Error'

definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
        description: 'The cause of the Error.'
```

Once you've done that you can reference the shared responses in the path.

```yaml
paths:
  /keys/:
    get:
      summary: 'Get All API Keys the caller has access to view.'
      responses:
        200:
          description: 'Successfully got Keys'
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ApiKeyResponse'
        400: 
          $ref: '#/responses/400'
        401:
          $ref: '#/responses/401'
        500:
          $ref: '#/responses/500'
```

At a minimum this gets you consistency with regards to the `response` description and any schema defined for that response type. I was really hoping for a way to group all of the common error responses and just reference the group but I haven't found any way to do that.

Comment: It seems that this answer is slightly outdated according to the [official documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/#reuse)