# Default 500 response from all paths in openapi

Tags: swagger, openapi

In openapi 2/3 I have a std error 500 response which looks simply like this:

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: Successful unlock
    schema:
      $ref: ../../../definitions/generic/message.yml
  '500':
    description: Something went wrong at our end!
```

Nice and easy, but this response is the same for all paths.

What is the method to ensure that all paths use this error 500 response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How not to copy-paste 3 generic error responses in almost all paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35921287/113116), [How can I add a 401 response to all paths in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36402289/113116)

Comment: Yea i saw this, but is it valid? That post is over 2 years old now and the openapi world has moved on a lot since then

Comment: Yes those answers are still valid.